Conflict RMQ and TypeOrm nestjs
I have conflict when I use TypeOrm => RMQ crash
IDK WHY.
Use library  golevelup/nestjs-rabbitmq
I waste 7 hours on this question..

@Module({
    imports: [
        ConfigModule.forRoot({
            isGlobal: true,
            envFilePath: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? '.env.production' : '.env.development',
        }),
        HttpModule,
        TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
            imports: [ConfigModule],
            useFactory: (configService: ConfigService) => ({
                type: 'postgres',
                host: configService.get<string>('DB_HOST', 'postgres'),
                port: parseInt(configService.get<string>('DB_PORT', '5432'), 10),
                username: configService.get<string>('DB_USERNAME', 'your_pgsql_username'),
                password: configService.get<string>('DB_PASSWORD', 'your_pgsql_password'),
                database: configService.get<string>('DB_DATABASE', '404sq'),
                entities: [UserData, UserProfile],
                synchronize: true,
                migrationsRun: true,
                migrations: [CreateDatabase1619811671274],
            }),
            inject: [ConfigService],
        }),
        RabbitMQModule.forRoot(RabbitMQModule, {
            exchanges: [
                {
                    name: 'AUTH',
                    type: 'topic',
                },
            ],
            uri: 'amqp://your_rabbitmq_username:your_rabbitmq_password@rabbitmq:5672',
        }),
        SignUpModule,
        SignInModule,
    ],
  
})
export class AppModule {}

commited lines
create modules
create services

I'm not exactly sure what it is you are trying to achieve.
But if you are trying to use some kind of RabbitMQ client, you can just make use of the ClientsModule provided my @nestjs/microservices.

I use standart Nestjs without @nestjs/microservices. with import
{ RabbitMQModule } from '@golevelup/nestjs-rabbitmq';
On my localhost it's work but in docker container work only when I comment TypeOrmModule
